# Can't login on any accounts and can't access a shell too. What can I do?

Tags: permissions, login

So I have an issue there... I am writing this on my phone please excuse me if it's too short or badly formatted (for the grammar too). I tried to start my computer this evening but I cannot connect to any of my accounts. It goes in a loop from the login screen. As I browsed...this issue could be a problem of permissions of my home folder. So I tried to get to a shell with the ctrl-alt-f[1-6] but it's just a black screen. I have no grub to chose to boot something else (my bios is fine wohoo). I guess I could download an Ubuntu iso but I have no micro usb to female usb connector to put it on a key. Not sure if I could boot on my phone (is that even possible ?). Thanks in advance for your advices ! Regards.

Edit 1: I may have something interesting there. As I try to login on my guest account I have a notification : "VBoxClient : the VirtualBox service is not running. Exiting.". I installed some vbox-related package maybe a week ago and everything was fine till then...

Edit2 : From what I have read this is unrelated.

Comment: So any TTY (Ctrl-Alt-F[1-2]),  don't give  lines like `Ubuntu 14.04LTS` and `mylaptopname login` ?  Also, `grub` just *has to be* there, but if that's an only OS on the machine it's set to have time out of 0,  i.e. not show up.   I suggest you get yourself a USB jump drive, install Ubuntu there, and use  [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery) , particularly the "failed update" part, on how to change root folder. Alter `/etc/default/grub` file as well as do any troubleshootings. Changing passwords might help, changing greeter to `gdm` might be a good idea too

Comment: Thanks I will post an answer. I manage   to get to the grub menu and boot an older img just fine.

Comment: Cool :) Looking towards that

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get to the grub menu holding the shift key and boot an older version of the kernel. It's seems to be working...not sure what was the exact problem. I'll update this answer if I discover something.

(FYI you can access a root shell from the recovery mode but it seems you need to mount your partitions after that)